# How can i rewrite my angular code more efficiently?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hi I am having an angular component class. In my ngOnInit() method I am making a few http requests and some logic before i populate my form . any idea what is the best way or cleanest code i can write .
I tried to rewrite with combinelatest rxjs operation but didnt work.

```
export class MessageHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  isGlobalAdmin: boolean = false;
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  cdrStatuses = CdrMessageStatus;
  cdrStatusKeys: any[];

  campaigns: CampaignUnpaginated[];
  inventories: FlightInventory[];
  flights: Flight[];
  accounts: Account[];
  currentUserAccount: Account;
  campaignStatusIds: string[];
  isLoading = true;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private accountService:AccountsService, 
    private campaignsService: CampaignsService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private flightsService: FlightsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

      this.campaignsService.getStatuses().subscribe(

        campaignStatuses => {
          this.campaignStatusIds = campaignStatuses.filter(
              status => (  status.code === CampaignStatusCode.READY
                ||  status.code === CampaignStatusCode.IN_PROGRESS
                ||  status.code === CampaignStatusCode.COMPLETE
                )
             ).map( element => element.id);
        }
      );

      if( this.authenticationService.authority === Authority.GLOBAL_ADMIN ){
        this.isGlobalAdmin = true;
      }

      if(!this.isGlobalAdmin){
        this.authenticationService.currentUser$.subscribe(
        (user) => this.currentUserAccount = user.account
        );
      }

      if(this.isGlobalAdmin) {
        this.flightsService.getInventories().subscribe(
          (inventories) => {
            this.inventories = inventories;
          }
        );
      } else {
        if(this.currentUserAccount.inventories){
          this.inventories = this.currentUserAccount.inventories;
        }
      }

     if(this.isGlobalAdmin){
      this.accountService.getUnpaginatedAccounts().subscribe(
        (accts) => {
          this.accounts = accts;
        }
        );
      }

    this.cdrStatusKeys = Object.keys(this.cdrStatuses);

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      range: [ [moment(),moment()], Validators.required],
      cdrStatus: [''],
      msisdn:[''],
      campaign: [''],
      inventory: [],
      flight: []
     }
    );

     if(this.isGlobalAdmin){
      this.formGroup.addControl('account',new FormControl());
      this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
     }

     this.rangeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value) => {


        this.campaignsService.getCampaignsWithinRange(
          { 
            accountIds : this.currentUserAccount? this.currentUserAccount.id: null,
            campaignStatuses: this.campaignStatusIds,
            rangeStartDate: (this.rangeControl.value[0]).toISOString(),
            rangeEndDate: (this.rangeControl.value[1]).toISOString()
          }
        ).subscribe(
          (value1) => {
            console.log(value1);
          }

        );;


      }
     );

  }

  get rangeControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('range') as FormControl;
  }

  get cdrStatusControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('cdrStatus') as FormControl;
  }

  get campaignControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('campaign') as FormControl;
  }

  get msisdnControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('msisdn') as FormControl;
  }

  get inventoryControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('inventory') as FormControl;
  }

  get flightControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('flight') as FormControl;
  }

  get accountControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('account') as FormControl;
  }

  getDatesFilters(dates: [Moment, Moment]) {
    if (!dates) {
      return null;
    }

    const [startDate, endDate] = dates;

    return {
      minStartDate: startDate.startOf('day').toISOString(),
      maxEndDate: endDate.endOf('day').toISOString()
    };
  }
}
```

if you can show me what is the best way to refactor the code. I am totally a newbie to UX programming

thank you

Comment: There is a lot of code, is there anything specifically that is not working as intended? If so please identify that code, and what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by collecting all the admin requests and the user requests:
One method called getGlobalAdminData or similar, and one getUserData.

There are a lot of useful RXJS observable operators out there: 
https://www.learnrxjs.io

When you have a lot of HTTP request where you want the response at the same time, use [zip()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html)

For a subscription in a subscription, [switchMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) is one useful operator.

If you have a lot of isGlobalAdmin checks, consider making an admin component instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrite my code like this . not sure this is the best way to rewrite the code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import { CampaignsService, AccountsService, AuthenticationService, CampaignUnpaginated, FlightsService, FlightInventory, Flight, Authority, Account, CampaignStatus, CampaignStatusCode } from '../../shared';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
import { map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PeformanceDateRange, CdrMessageStatus} from '../../shared';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

    @Component({
      selector: 'pc-messagehistory',
      templateUrl: './message-history.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./message-history.component.scss']
    })
    export class MessageHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

      isGlobalAdmin: boolean = false;
      formGroup: FormGroup;

      cdrStatuses = CdrMessageStatus;
      cdrStatusKeys: any[];

      campaigns: CampaignUnpaginated[];
      inventories: FlightInventory[];
      flights: Flight[];
      accounts: Account[];
      currentUserAccount: Account;
      campaignStatusIds: string[];
      isLoading = true;
      isInnerLoading = true;

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
        private accountService:AccountsService, 
        private campaignsService: CampaignsService,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private flightsService: FlightsService) {}

      ngOnInit() {


        this.cdrStatusKeys = Object.keys(this.cdrStatuses);

        combineLatest(this.campaignsService.getStatuses(),
                          this.authenticationService.currentUser$,
                          of(this.authenticationService.authority)
                      ).subscribe(([campaignStatuses,user,authority]) => {

                  this.campaignStatusIds = campaignStatuses.filter(
                      status => (  status.code === CampaignStatusCode.READY
                        ||  status.code === CampaignStatusCode.IN_PROGRESS
                        ||  status.code === CampaignStatusCode.COMPLETE
                        )
                      ).map( element => element.id);

                      this.currentUserAccount = user.account;

                      if( authority === Authority.GLOBAL_ADMIN ){
                        this.isGlobalAdmin = true;
                      }

                      if(this.isGlobalAdmin) {

                        this.isInnerLoading = true;

                         combineLatest(this.flightsService.getInventories(), this.accountService.getUnpaginatedAccounts())
                          .subscribe( ([inventories,accounts]) => {
                            this.inventories = inventories;
                            this.accounts = accounts;
                            this.isInnerLoading = false;
                            }
                          );
                      } else {
                        if(this.currentUserAccount.inventories){
                          this.inventories = this.currentUserAccount.inventories;
                          this.isInnerLoading = false;
                        }
                      }

                      this.isLoading = false;
                    }
            );




        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
          range: [ [moment(),moment()], Validators.required],
          cdrStatus: [''],
          msisdn:[''],
          campaign: [''],
          inventory: [],
          flight: []
         }
        );

         if(this.isGlobalAdmin){
          this.formGroup.addControl('account',new FormControl());
          this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
         }

         this.rangeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
          (value) => {

            this.campaignsService.getCampaignsWithinRange(
              { 
                accountIds : this.currentUserAccount? this.currentUserAccount.id: null,
                campaignStatuses: this.campaignStatusIds,
                rangeStartDate: (this.rangeControl.value[0]).toISOString(),
                rangeEndDate: (this.rangeControl.value[1]).toISOString()
              }
            ).subscribe(
              (value1) => {
                console.log(value1);
              }
            );
          }
         );

      }

      get rangeControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formGroup.get('range') as FormControl;
      }

      get cdrStatusControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formGroup.get('cdrStatus') as FormControl;
      }

      get campaignControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formGroup.get('campaign') as FormControl;
      }

      get msisdnControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formGroup.get('msisdn') as FormControl;
      }

      get inventoryControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formGroup.get('inventory') as FormControl;
      }

      get flightControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formGroup.get('flight') as FormControl;
      }

      get accountControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formGroup.get('account') as FormControl;
      }

      getDatesFilters(dates: [Moment, Moment]) {
        if (!dates) {
          return null;
        }

        const [startDate, endDate] = dates;

        return {
          minStartDate: startDate.startOf('day').toISOString(),
          maxEndDate: endDate.endOf('day').toISOString()
        };
      }


    }
```